# Why wont postgres let me drop an index?

Tags: postgresql, psql, drop

I'm connected to the database, and I'd like to drop the index for the particular table. It shows up in the indexes but it won't let me drop it from the table. Do I need to specify which table the index belongs to from a list of tables. If so how would I do that?

```
geo_vernon=# \d fakedata.fakedata3
                                       Table "fakedata.fakedata3"
   Column   |       Type       | Collation | Nullable |                     Default                      
------------+------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
 OID        | bigint           |           |          | 
 first_name | text             |           |          | 
 last_name  | text             |           |          | 
 edited_occ | text             |           |          | 
 chgd_add   | text             |           |          | 
 Lat        | double precision |           |          | 
 Long       | double precision |           |          | 
 year       | bigint           |           |          | 
 pkey       | integer          |           | not null | nextval('fakedata.fakedata3_pkey_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "fakedata3_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pkey)
    "idx_first_name" btree (first_name)
    "last_name_idx" gin (last_name gin_trgm_ops)

geo_vernon=# DROP INDEX last_name_idx
geo_vernon-# ;
ERROR:  index "last_name_idx" does not exist
geo_vernon=#
```

Comment: `drop index fakedata.last_name_idx`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was trying ```DROP INDEX fakedata.fakedata3.last_name_idx``` and it wasn't working.